# Add an image based on product title

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to add a sticker to a product based on the product title. Will loop through an array of names and, if is one of the names, will add the sticker. I would need to add it to the closest product block only. Here's the code if you can let me know if I'm on the right track:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var text = $('h4').text();
  var names = ["Title1", "Title2", "Title3"];
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) { 
    if (text === names[i]) {
      $('<div class="product"><ul><li><div class="sticker"><img src="sticker.png"></div></li></ul></div>').prependTo($(this).closest('.sticker_wrapper')); 
    }                   
  }
});
```

Here's sample html code for one of the products/product block that would be similar across the page to correspond with the javascript:

```
<div class="sticker_wrapper"></div>
<div>
  <h4>Title1</h4>
</div>
```

If there's any help or if you can suggest corrections/improvements that would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two main issues in your code. Firstly, you're getting the text of all `h4` elements in one go and then comparing them all to the individual elements in the array. Secondly, the DOM traversal logic isn't quite right, as `.sticker_wrapper` isn't a parent of the `h4`, so `closest()` alone won't work. You would need to get the closest `div` parent, then the sibling `.sticker_wrapper`. Try this:

```js
var names = ["Title1", "Title2", "Title3"];
var sticker = '<div class="product"><ul><li><div class="sticker"><img src="sticker.png"></div></li></ul></div>';

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('h4').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().trim();
    if (names.indexOf(text) != -1)      
      $(this).closest('div').prev('.sticker_wrapper').append(sticker);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sticker_wrapper"></div>
<div>
  <h4>Title1</h4>
</div>
<div class="sticker_wrapper"></div>
<div>
  <h4>Title Foo</h4>
</div>
<div class="sticker_wrapper"></div>
<div>
  <h4>Title3</h4>
</div>
```

Note the use of `indexOf()` in the code above to find a match in the array, instead of explicitly looping through.